# Should ControlCenter.app listen to port 5000/tcp on a normal macOS Monterey system?

Tags: macos, network, security, monterey

I fetched the data below using `lsof -i:5000` and `ps aux` commands.

```
COMMAND    PID   USER        FD   TYPE  DEVICE              SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
ControlCe  6560  myusername  22u  IPv4  0xab7124fb1106e193  0t0       TCP  *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
```

```
PID   PATH
6560  /System/Library/CoreServices/ControlCenter.app/Contents/MacOS/ControlCenter
```

I worry this is not normal and don’t understand why that app should have an open network listening connection. Can someone explain if this is normal?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Port `5000` is now used for **Airplay** as well as port `7000` as of macOS Monterey. So **yes**, **it's normal** ! Apple decided to use those ports even though a lot of developers use those ports by default.

### macOS 12 Monterey

You can toggle that off by unchecking **Ariplay Receiver** option in **System Preferences** > **Sharing**, at the bottom of the services list.

[image: system preferences app, sharing]

### macOS 13 Ventura and newer

As of macOS 13 Ventura and thanks to [@bryanbraun](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/62045/bryanbraun)'s comment, you can toggle off the option in "**System Settings…**" > **General** > **AirDrop & Handoff** > **AirPlay Receiver**

[image: system settings app, AirDrop & Handoff setting page]

Comment: See also https://chrishannah.me/monterey-blocking-ports-5000-and-7000/

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do this via CLI?

Comment: Note: If you're running into this on Ventura, the new place to disable this is in System Preferences > General > AirDrop & Handoff > Airplay Receiver

Comment: Wow @tama how did you get to that conclusion? I would like to know

Comment: @Erick I should have made a supposition more than a statement